# Why doesn't my python socket connect to another computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server, client

So i've recently started testing out sockets and i have managed to create a server and client, which are both working together when i run them on the same pc. However, when i put in the server on a diffrent computer it gives me the following error: ""TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond""

Here is my server:

```
import socket
import pyautogui
import os

computerIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

def Main():
    host = computerIP
    port = 5000
    value = 0
    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.bind((host,port))

    mySocket.listen(1)
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if not data:
                    break
            elif data == "shift":
                pyautogui.keyDown("shift")
            elif data == "relshift":
                pyautogui.keyUp("shift")
            elif data == "logout":
                os.popen("shutdown -l")
            elif data == "click":
                pyautogui.click()
                pyautogui.click()                                
            print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))
            data = str(data).upper()
            print ("sending: " + str(data))
            conn.send(data.encode())

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

My client:

```
import socket


def Main():
        host = #same ip as server
        port = 5000

        mySocket = socket.socket()
        mySocket.connect((host,port))

        message = input(" -> ")

        while message != 'q':
                mySocket.send(message.encode())
                data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()

                print ('Received from server: ' + data)

                message = input(" -> ")

        mySocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

OS: Windows 8.1
Python verion: 3.4

I tried looking this up on the internet but since i'm pretty new to python i didn't understand much.

Tell me if there is anything i need to clearify.

Comment: Port 5000 on the host seems to be blocked by a firewall if accessed from your PC with the client.

Comment: So what should I do about this?

Comment: Lojas, you can use `telnet` to check if the server port is reachable from the client.

Comment: @VikasTiwari But what should i do when the connection fails? Try diffrent ports or what?

Comment: If the connection fails, it usually means that the port is blocked by a firewall and that is why the connection times out. The firewall could be a network firewall, application firewall or a system firewall. In the simplest case it could just be a windows firewall. Try opening the port to allow incoming access to the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the port is blocked due to some firewall.

Use `socket.connect_ex()` instead of `socket.connect()`. If the connection  succeeds it would return 0, otherwise the value of the errno variable will help you debug why the connection failed.

Prior to the connection also use `socket.settimeout()` so that the connection times out in the given no. of seconds.

Comment: socket.settimeout() gives me Following error: TypeError: settimeout() takes exactly one argument (0 given) I added it under mySocket.connect_ex((host,port))

Comment: Right, you must provide the no. of seconds as an argument. For ex - `socket.settimeout(5)`

Comment: Well, i still didn't get a connection to the server, however, the error changed to the following:  File "C:\Users\Lojas\Desktop\client.py", line 15, in Main
    mySocket.send(message.encode())
socket.timeout: timed out and when I remove the socket.settimeout() I get this: OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Comment: Okay, so check the Antivirus, Windows firewall or any other Firewall installed (on the machine you are running the socket server on) and make sure that they all allow the port 5000.

Comment: Try Googling - "How to open ports in windows 10 "

Comment: Finally, i've been trying this for hours but I didn't realise that my anti virus didn't let me allow the port for some reason. However, is there any way that python can allow a port? Then i could put it inside of the server code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136581/discussion-between-vikas-tiwari-and-lojas).